# Contact Management from various instant messengers and websites

Tags: windows, macos, contacts, google-contacts

I have Facebook, various websites, Windows Live Messenger, Adium, Pidgin, etc etc etc

I need a way of corralling all the information I have on people so rather than looking at 20 different websites for 20 different profiles, and 5 different machines, I would rather be able to convert all my chat logs into a common form, and easily put as much of this information into a single place.

Currently I mainly use Windows Live Messenger on my two main machines, one of which is a macbook and has Adium/OS X 10.6 in Boot Camp too. I also have Google Contacts to try and minimize duplication by using push on my phone.

How can I solve the problem, and if not, how can I minimize it? (Currently running with Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Pidgin ? Pidgin supports almost all chat protocols (including Facebook) and you get to have a common chat log. To [keep the logs in sync](http://www.chriserk.com/blog/index.php/synchronize-pidgin-chat-logs-across-multiple-platforms/), use a service like [Dropbox](http://getdroxbox.com).

> One problem with just installing
>   DropBox, it can only sync what’s in
>   it’s folder. We can’t move the chat
>   logs folder of pidgin, so we need to
>   create symbolic links, and junctions
>   between the folders on each computer.
>   The process of doing this may vary
>   depending on the platform you’re
>   using. First, we need to locate the
>   DropBox folder, and the logs folder
>   for Pidgin.
>
> Linux: `~/.purple/logs/`
>
> Windows XP: `C:\Documents and
>   Settings\username\Application Data`
>
> Vista:
>   `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\.purple\logs`
>
> If you’re on linux, then you can use
>   the ln command to create a symbolic
>   link:
>
> `ln -s [TARGET DIRECTORY OR FILE]
>   ./[SHORTCUT]`
>
> If you’re in Windows XP, you’ll need
>   to download and use [this shell
>   extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).
>
> In Windows Vista/7, you can use the
>   mklink command.
>
> To create symbolic link called `foo`
>   to reference to
>   `c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`
>
> `C:\test>mklink foo
>   c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`

Comment: Ah, how would I sync them across machines?

Comment: You could use Dropbox ( http://getdropxbox.com )  to keep all of them in sync. See this article - http://www.chriserk.com/blog/index.php/synchronize-pidgin-chat-logs-across-multiple-platforms/

Answer (score 0):

Use Meebo.  Meebo.com can log into most of your contacts into a common single-signon, web-based application.  No need to install anything unless you want to.

Comment: but then I loose all my chat logs completely!!